# Is this program is correct -->using C++0x N3242

Tags: c++, c++11

> A class is a type. Its name becomes a class-name (9.1) within its
>   scope.
>
> ```
>     class-name:
>            identiﬁer
>            simple-template-id
> ```
>
> Class-speciﬁer s and elaborated-type-speciﬁer s (7.1.6.3)
>   are used to make class-names. An object of a class consists of a (possibly empty)
>   sequence of members and base class objects.
>
> ```
>     class-speciﬁer:
>            class-head { member-speciﬁcationopt }
>     class-head:
>            class-key attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt
>     class-head-name
>     class-virt-speciﬁer-seqopt
>     base-clauseopt
>     class-key attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt
>     base-clauseopt
>
>         class-head-name:
>            nested-name-speciﬁeropt class-name
>       class-virt-speciﬁer-seq:
>            class-virt-speciﬁer
>            class-virt-speciﬁer-seq class-virt-speciﬁer
>       class-virt-speciﬁer:
>            final
>            explicit
>       class-key:
>            class
>            struct
>            union
> ```
>
> A class-virt-speciﬁer-seq shall contain
>   at most one of each
>   class-virt-speciﬁer .
>
> A class-speciﬁer whose class  head omits
>   the class-head-name deﬁnes an unnamed
>   class. [   Note: An unnamed class thus
>   can’t be final  or explicit. — end
>   note ]

HERE: they used the --> final, explicit as class-virt-speciﬁer:

for this shall i use like this :

```
 1) struct A{ void f();};
    struct B final : A{void f();};
    int main() {   return 0; }
 2) struct A{ void f();};
    struct B explicit : A{void f();};
   int main() {   return 0; }
   etc...
```

Can any one tell the correct usage of thi ...if it is wrong

AND :Please tell me which compiler is going to support this feature.(I know VC++,GCC 4.6.0 is supporting many features)
But GCC is not supporting the above feature..Please suggest me what to do to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it would be ok, but I don't think any compiler implements this yet.

It is also subject to change, as there is a request to remove this:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3234.pdf